# Storage capacity not displayed in Datastax Ops Center

Tags: ubuntu, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, opscenter

I added new nodes in my DSE cluster and these are not reporting any storage capacity whereas :

- Nodes are up and running without any problems
- I can see them in the ring in Ops Center

This only happens on new installed nodes with the same version of DSE but with a minor difference on the ubuntu version : new servers run on Ubuntu `14.04.4 LTS` and "old" servers run on Ubuntu `14.04.3 LTS`.

iosta is installed on all of our servers.

Thanks

Comment: My DSE version : 4.8.4

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be related to:

[OpsCenter does not show available storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35875048/opscenter-does-not-show-available-storage)

In summary, /proc/mounts seems to output root partition pointing to a symlink that in turn points to the actual node/partition location.

Thus, df outputs different locations (a sym link and a file) on two different `df` use cases: `df -H` and `df <file>`. One by node or label, and one by-uuid.

14.04.4 LTS (and 14.04.4) might be based on Debian Wheezy, which in turn had this bug reported (also related):

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=653073

Which is related to the same issue.

Please advise if your df (and /proc/mounts) output shows this behavior or if it seems to be a different case.

If this is your case, we'll get this fixed for next OpsCenter version. In the meantime, you might want to run the fix described here:

https://blog.mbentley.net/2013/09/df-reports-root-fs-as-by-uuid-symlink-instead-of-actual-device

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Indeed we have the bug you describe. We will wait for the next OpsCenter version.